# Chart.js Tooltip underneath Pie Chart

Tags: tooltip, chart.js, chart.js2

I got a Chart.js Pie Chart with Tooltips. The Tooltip for every slice is always starting kind of in the middle of every slice. Is it possible to put every tooltip underneath the whole chart? So no matter on which slice I hover, the tooltip is always at the same position centered underneath the chart. Seems like there is no option or something for this and I can't really think of a workaround in the tooltip callbacks.

I am using Chart.js 2.5.0.

Comment: Can you add some code or a JSFiddle?